# Hook into GWT before compilation to add more sources

Tags: java, gwt

I have successfully emulated some source files using the `<super-source>` feature (GWT 2.7).

But I'm getting "incorrect package name" errors in Eclipse.

The GWT compiler needs the Java files to have the original package name, but Eclipse needs them to have the package name that corresponds to their place in the source folder.

Is there is a way to programmatically hook into the GWT compiler before it compiles and add the emulated source files? I'm thinking that way I could adjust the package declaration using `replaceAll()` before the GWT compiler looks at them.

As a temporary workround, I am running a separate step before compiling that does this trick. It works, but it would be better to have it as part of the real compilation process so that refreshing the page in Super Dev Mode will automatically perform this process.

I've looked at Generators but I can't see any way to do it with them.

The other idea I've considered is making the copying part of the Eclipse compilation. Every time I save one of the emulated classes, it can copy the source and repackage it. But I'm on Windows and setting that up is a bit of a faff and it's not part of the normal compilation, so I'd have to replicate those actions in my build script.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse complains because it wants to compile them, which it shouldn't do.
You should exclude the super-sources from Eclipse, so it only see them as resources / text files.
If you really need Eclipse's features when editing those files, then you can add your `super`  (or however it's called) "package" as a source folder, and Eclipse will no longer complain about mismatching package names (but could have issues with duplicate classes between the original and the one from super-sources; also, Eclipse will compile them, and if they end up in your classpath at runtime / DevMode, it could possibly fail; your app using the super-sources instead of the original classes in the JVM)

TL;DR: the problem is Eclipse, not GWT.

Comment: Thanks Thomas. I want to have both versions in the same project and use the Eclipse Java editor on both. Unfortunately none of those suggestions will allow it. It would all be great if GWT did not care that the package declaration match exactly - if it could translate a super-prefixed package into a true package name. My approach does this and it works but is a bit clumsy. I assume then there's no way to hook into the compiler that you know of?